# Is it possible to replace null in case when I don't know field name like simply using * in select query

Tags: mysql, database

**Replace null values with just a blank**

**MS SQL**

- Select IsNull(ColName, '') As ColName From TableName

**MySQL**

- Select IfNull(ColName, '') As ColName From TableName

IFNULL(expr1,expr2)

If expr1 is not NULL, IFNULL() returns expr1; otherwise it returns expr2. IFNULL() returns a numeric or string value, depending on the context in which it is used.

Without knowing column na e how can I do this ?

Comment: Just write all columns separately, you can't attach function to multiple columns as simply as `select *`

Comment: Isn't it strange you want to impose a logic for unknown column (to you)?

Comment: @OtoShavadze without writing column_name

Comment: @ajreal If  a table consists of many fields then it is not good to write all the column's name again and again

Comment: I don't agree with your logic. I would suggest to keep the database result and only perform casting from null to blank at the presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the column names then you need to first get all the columns for that table and dynamically generate `SELECT` query, e.g.:

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'mytable';
```

This will give you the columns. You can iterte through the list, construct the `SELECT` query with comma separated `IFNULL(col, '')` and execute it.

Another approach would be to use `SELECT *` in the query and handle `null`/`empty` values in the user interface/service layer.

Comment: This will become double headache and double task and takes a lot of time by running query 2 times

Comment: Added another approach, however, these are the only ways to achieve that.